# Checking for undefined variable not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am checking if a variable is defined or not. It is working right in Firefox and when it comes to Chrome it is not working:

```
if(window[myClass] == undefined)
{
    return;
}
```

If the variable is not defined it should return.

I am using `window[myClass]` because I am taking name of the id from `onclick` event and using same named variable as id if variable is defined then else part should or if not defined then if part should work.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine in Chrome.

Comment: add this before your check: console.log(window[myclass]); and see the o/p

Comment: Is `myclass` a variable or a string?

Comment: Can't see how jQuery is relevant here, removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last sentence in your question, sounds like `myClass` is actually ID of some element in your document.

In such case you should use such code to check if such element really exists:

```
if (!document.getElementById(myClass))
    return;
```

This will cancel the function when *element* with such ID does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

You should be doing something like this to check whether `window[myclass]` is defined or not:

```
if (typeof window[myclass] === 'undefined') {
```

But if I understand the question correctly, you might be looking to see if `window[myclass]` exists. Usually you do that like so:

```
if (window.hasOwnProperty(myclass)) {
```

Also, is `myclass` a variable or a string (`'myclass'`)?

Comment: thanx man your right (window.hasOwnProperty(myClass) is working for me  i m new jquery and javascript do suggest any good video tutorial or any book for learn jquery ) any way thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof window[myClass] !== 'undefined') {
    //do stuff
} else {
    alert('undefined');
}
```